# Increase font size in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Can one increase the font size of code in Bigquery ?

I tried google and Youtube but didn't find any answer.

The default font size is very small for my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is with the Command Palette, the tool used to configure any styling settings (among other actions). To access it right click in your query editor and click Command Palette. There you can look for `Font` and you will see some options, among which there's the `Editor Zoom In`. Use it as many times as needed to adjust it to your own preferences.